# How to avoid boldface citations with hyperref

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

When using the `hyperref` package, citations are automatically typeset as hyperlinks to the bibliography. According to the documentation, the color of these links can be set.

Is there any way to get rid of the boldface? In combination with the `amsalpha` bibliography style, citations appear in the text in a way too heavy font.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  `hyperref` does not make these bold by default, so there is something else we need to know about your document.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your spare information I provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your issue can't be reproduced with TeX Live 2012 (updated).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}
\begin{document}
\cite{article-full} Aam86
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]